# 2D arrays in firebase using Flutter (Dart)

Tags: arrays, firebase, flutter, dart

I have created a list of list of String which is a 2D array
now I want to upload to firebase database server but do firebase supports 2D array?

```
List<List<String>> data = [
    ['5', '2', '2', '7'],
    ['8', '8', '9', '7'],
    ['78', '7', '8', '7'],
  ];
```

how to upload this array and retrieve back in original form in Flutter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map property in firebase create a map then inside your map area create a array then put your values to the array

[image]

```
 Firestore.instance.collection('your collection').document(some_docID).setData({
       'map1': {
        'key1': ['value1', 'value3'],
        'key2': ['value2', 'value4'],
      }});
```

https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-map-an-array-of-objects-from-cloud-firestore-to-a-list-of-objects-122e579eae10

this medium article shows how to retrieve data.

Comment: can you show me code of how to set data and retrive it back

Comment: @SanketJain I edit my answer. I guess It will work.

Comment: you are awasome buddy